# How can this all-NFA be converted to an DFA

Tags: logic, determinant, automata

an all-NFA was defined in Sipse as such:

A (Q, Σ, δ, q0, F) that accepts x ∈ Σ∗ if every possible state that M could reach after reading input x is in F, so not at least one.

If any branch in an all-NFA computation reaches an implicit or explicit sink
state, the input is not accepted.

I am trying to adjust a normal NFA to DFA conversion but I cant quite get this one. Any tips?

Comment: Can you first convert it to NFA?

Answer (score 2):

Such an all-NFA does *not* accept a word $x$ if and only if there is a state in $Q\setminus F$ that can be reached by processing $x$. So it can be turned into a normal NFA for the *complement* of your language $L$ by exchanging the final and non-final states, i.e., the NFA $(Q, \Sigma, \delta, q_0, Q \setminus F)$ accepts $\Sigma^* \setminus L$. Now turn this into a DFA for $\Sigma^* \setminus L$ and do the same trick in the resulting DFA to get a DFA for your original language $L$.

Comment: I guess this is to advanced for my level since im not sure how to complement. But I will look into it, Thank you for your answer

Comment: The complement of a language $L$ is just all words in $\Sigma^*$ that are not in $L$.

Comment: I tried to explain it like this, but not sure if this my idea is correct                                                                                                                                          F =  (Q, Σ, δ, q0, F)  (an all-NFA)

We construct now a DFA  M =  (Q’, Σ’, δ’, q’0, F)

As done in class:

Q’ = P(Q) , KεQ’ , a ε Σ
δ’(R,a) = rεRE(δ(r,a))
q’0 = E(q0)

We give an input x

We let K be a set of states for which the all-NFA could be after input.

Now when x enters the DFA, the DFA will end at  K.
So M accepts x if KεF’ which is equivalent to K⊂F